# Counting all occurrences in a .txt file using Python

Tags: python

I am new to programming and would like some help. I have a .txt file with 300K lines of input.

Input file

ANDY 
ROB 
ANDY 
RON 
ALEX 
RON 
MANDY 
....
MANDY \

I need to find how many different names are their count.

Sample output

ANDY 20 
RON 12 
ROB 33 
...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to store the name-amount pairs.

Create an empty dictionary, and then read the file line-by-line. On each line, if you encounter a new name, you add it to the dictionary with the value 1. If the name is already in the dictionary, just add one to the value. Finally just iterate over the dictionary and write each pair on the output file.

Something like this:

```
d = dict()
f = open("file.txt", 'r')
while True:
    line = f.readline().split('\n')[0]
    if line == '':
        break
    if line in d:
        d[line] = d[line] + 1
    else:
        d[line] = 1
f.close()
g = open("output.txt", "w")
for key in d:
    g.write(key + " " + str(d[key]) + '\n')
g.close()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files: "*It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects.*" Also, better to use `for line in f` than a manual `while True`-break-on-EOF loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

word_counts = Counter()

with open("NAMES.TXT") as f:
    for line in f.readlines(): #last line of file needs to be a blank line
        word_counts.update([line[:-1]]) #chops off the '\n'

print(word_counts)
```

The Counter needs the words to be in a list, else it counts the letters in the word [line[:-1]]

Comment: You can use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69216759/edit) button under your post to update it. Put clarifications and modifications into the post, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility that is similar in design to vdaiep's solution involves using the `try-except` idiom as control flow:

```
d = dict()


with open("file.txt", "r") as fp:
    line = fp.readline().strip()
    while line:
        try:
            d[line] += 1
        except KeyError:
            d[line] = 1
        line = fp.readline().strip()


with open("output.txt", "w") as fp:
    for k,v in d.items():
        fp.write("{} {}\n".format(k, str(v)))
```